# How to create a view to display poll results formatted as a chart?

Tags: 7, views, polls, charts

By using core module **poll**, every time somebody participates in it, the poll module creates data representing the selected option of the poll, called 'poll results'.

How can these poll results be transformed using the [views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module? By creating a view and using a relationship to poll results, I only get 0, no matter what.

After I succeed in showing some tabular format of these results, I want to further enhance this view to display these poll results using some 3rd party charting app. This by using some charting module with views integration, which uses a charting library as its rendering engine.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

About this phrase in the question:

> display poll results using 3rd party charting app

To create charts in Drupal, consider the [comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) as a possible place to start from, to find the module that best fits your needs. That comparison includes the following: *"[Poll Chart Block](https://www.drupal.org/project/poll_chart) displays poll's results in a block, with a selectable chart type, and using the [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module."* So it looks like what you're trying to achieve already exists as a contributed module, no?

Be aware: I'm a new (co-) maintainer of [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart), and the author of the [comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985).